# How to get all beans of specified interface which also implements other interfaces

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inversion-of-control

Here I have 3 Interfaces: `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB` and `SharedInterface`

```
public interface InterfaceA {
    /**
     * print some message
     */
    void printMsg();
}
```

```
public interface InterfaceB {
    /**
     * print some message
     */
    void printMsg();
}
```

```
public interface SharedInterface {
    /**
     * print some message
     */
    void printSharedMsg();
}
```

and there are 3 implementations of these interfaces:

```
public class ImplementA1 implements InterfaceA, SharedInterface {
    @Override
    public void printMsg() {
        System.out.println("this is message of interfaceA1");
    }

    @Override
    public void printSharedMsg() {
        System.out.println("this is shared message from ImplementA1");
    }
}
```

```
public class ImplementA2 implements InterfaceA, SharedInterface {
    @Override
    public void printMsg() {
        System.out.println("this is message of interfaceA2");
    }

    @Override
    public void printSharedMsg() {
        System.out.println("this is shared message from ImplementA2");
    }
}
```

```
public class ImplementB implements InterfaceB, SharedInterface {
    @Override
    public void printMsg() {
        System.out.println("this is message of interfaceB");
    }

    @Override
    public void printSharedMsg() {
        System.out.println("this is shared message from ImplementB");
    }
}
```

`ImplementA1` and `ImplementA2` are the same type of operation, `ImplementB` is another type of operation. So I decided to develop 2 config class to register ImplementA1,ImplementA2 and ImplementB which is showing below.

```
@Configuration
public class InterfaceAConfig {
    @Bean
    public InterfaceA registerInterfaceA1(){
        return new ImplementA1();
    }

    @Bean
    public InterfaceA registerInterfaceA2(){
        return new ImplementA2();
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class InterfaceBConfig {
    @Bean
    public InterfaceB registerInterfaceB(){
        return new ImplementB();
    }
}
```

Now I want to let all beans which implement `SharedInterface` print their message in a component. And it works well,here is the code:

```
@Component
@AutoConfigureAfter(value = {
    InterfaceAConfig.class,
    InterfaceBConfig.class})
public class SharedInterfaceComponent implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>, ApplicationContextAware {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    //print shared message after IOC container refreshed
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        usingContextGetBean();
    }

    private void usingContextGetBean() {
        Map<String, SharedInterface> beans = this.applicationContext.getBeansOfType(SharedInterface.class);
        System.out.println(beans.size());
        for (SharedInterface bean : beans.values()) {
            bean.printSharedMsg();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

But I found another way of inject beans to component, using

```
@Autowired
List<TargetType> myListName
```

So I decided to change my `SharedInterfaceComponent` to this for test, and it worked:

```
@Component
@AutoConfigureAfter(value = {
    InterfaceAConfig.class,
    InterfaceBConfig.class})
public class SharedInterfaceComponent  implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>, ApplicationContextAware {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    //todo why do spring failed due to this autowire?
    @Autowired
    private List<InterfaceA> autowiredList;

    //print shared message after IOC container refreshed
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        usingAutowiredGerBean();
        //usingContextGetBean();
    }

    private void usingAutowiredGerBean() {
        for (InterfaceA interfaceA : autowiredList) {
            if (SharedInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(interfaceA.getClass())){
                ((SharedInterface) interfaceA).printSharedMsg();
            }
        }
    }

    private void usingContextGetBean() {
        Map<String, SharedInterface> beans = this.applicationContext.getBeansOfType(SharedInterface.class);
        System.out.println(beans.size());
        for (SharedInterface bean : beans.values()) {
            bean.printSharedMsg();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext=applicationContext;
    }
}
```

But when I tried to use `SharedInterface` instead of `InerfaceA` to get beans from IOC , it goes wrong. The code is showing below:

```
@Component
@AutoConfigureAfter(value = {
    InterfaceAConfig.class,
    InterfaceBConfig.class})
public class SharedInterfaceComponent  implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>, ApplicationContextAware {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    //todo why do spring failed due to this autowire?
    @Autowired
    private List<SharedInterface> autowiredList;

    //print shared message after IOC container refreshed
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        usingAutowiredGerBean();
        //usingContextGetBean();
    }

    private void usingAutowiredGerBean() {
        for (SharedInterface sharedInterface : autowiredList) {
            if (SharedInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(sharedInterface.getClass())){
                ((SharedInterface) sharedInterface).printSharedMsg();
            }
        }
    }

    private void usingContextGetBean() {
        Map<String, SharedInterface> beans = this.applicationContext.getBeansOfType(SharedInterface.class);
        System.out.println(beans.size());
        for (SharedInterface bean : beans.values()) {
            bean.printSharedMsg();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext=applicationContext;
    }
}
```

In this Demo the application will fail and showing

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field autowiredList in com.wwstation.test.config.SharedInterfaceComponent required a bean of type 'java.util.List' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.util.List' in your configuration.
```

But in my other projects, the same situation will not lead to a crush, I can get `SharedInterface` by using `@Autowired` but there I can only get beans implement `InterfaceA` or `InterfaceB` but never all of them. I thought, the not crushing case may be caused by some of my dependencies in other projects.
Can anyone help me about how to get all the `SharedInterface` more graceful? Thanks alot!

Comment: In your `InterfaceAConfig` or `InterfaceBConfig`, shouldn't it be define `SharedInterface` beans, not `InterfaceA` or `InterfaceB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your configuration.

```java
@Bean
public InterfaceA registerInterfaceA1(){
    return new ImplementA1();
}
```

The problem with this is that Spring will use the return type of the method to see if it fullfils injection points (in this case your list). As `InterfaceA` isn't a `SharedInterface` eventually it will fail as there are no beans that implement the `SharedInterface` according to your configuration!.

What you should do with your own beans is to be as specific as possible in the return type. So instead of `InterfaceA` make it return the actual class `ImplementA1` and `ImplementA2`. That way Spring, at configuration time, can determine that those implement `SharedInterface` and use those to fill the list.

```java
@Bean
public ImplementA1 registerInterfaceA1(){
    return new ImplementA1();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Inspired by your suggestion, I tried to create 2 interfaces `SharedInterfaceA` and `SharedInterfaceB` to extend `InterfaceA`, `InterfaceB` and `SharedInterface`, and register beans with `SharedInterfaceA` and `SharedInterfaceB` , then I can use `@Autowired` to grab all the implementations of `SharedInterface`, and I can also use `@Autowired` to grab implementations of `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB`

Comment: You can just return the actual type, you don't (nor should) need to create all t hose different kinds of interfaces for each possible combination.